# Add HTML tags inside the variable, which contains data returned from firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

So i have a firestore response like this,

[image]

I want to add hyperlink inside the typescript variable.
{{task.title}} gives me this data on my component. Now i need to add link to the person's profile on person's name only(dev2). How can i implement this.
g

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
var title= "Dev2 changed the Status to <b> Closed</b> on TT-2";

var firstWord = title.replace(/ .*/,'');
```

The code will give you the `Dev2` as output. Then you can apply the link as you wish.

Comment: It ain't that simple. The name can be of multiple words. And this data is asynchronous. I would need to do it on run time. When data binding is happening. I would need to add html element on name. Let me know if you this.

Comment: Does that mean the message will be same every time i.e. `changed the status` will be always there?

Comment: No it will also be different. And i can't do anything in typescript. i need to do this in my html.

Comment: Then the `title` should contain `any symbol` which will separate `name` present in it. Otherwise, whatever you are asking is not possible.